# Global functions and ambiguous arguments NULL vs. char* between vs 2013 and GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

I am trying to understand what the currenct C++14 standard says about resolving an ambiguous function call, mostly because I am seeing a difference between GCC 4.9.1, and Visual Studio 2013 update 3

Here's the code (exactly the same for both MS and GCC):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(char *str, int chars) { cout << "f(char*, int)"; }
void f(char *first, char *second) { cout << "f(char*, char*)"; }

int main()
{
    char *hello = "Hello, World";
    f(hello, NULL); //which f gets called?

    char c; cin.get(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio calls `f(char*, int)` using default vs flags
GCC gives me a compiler error: call of overloaded 'f(char*&, NULL)' is ambiguous. gcc using only the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` and it has no choice but to use `char*` because there's no implicit conversion from `nullptr` to `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what `NULL` is defined to be.

MSVC defines it as `0`, so the `int` overload is an exact match and is preferred.

GCC defines it as the compiler internal `__null`, causing an ambiguity on 64-bit because `__null`'s type there is `long`. (It appears that `__null`'s type is `int` on 32-bit, so it picks the `int` overload when compiling for 32-bit.)

The standard permits `NULL` to be defined as any C++ null pointer constant, including `nullptr`, in which case it would unambigously pick the two pointer overload, or `0L`, which would be once again ambiguous (as going from a `long` to both `int` and `char *` involves a conversion).

The moral: Don't use `NULL` for a null pointer. Use `nullptr`.